# Converting data frame into matrix

Tags: r, matrix

How can I convert my data frame, "fruits" into a matrix

```
> fruits
      Month Apple   Mango   Banana
1      June  149579 36051   28124
2      July  198742 37228   30354
3    August  397145 36483   31140
4 September  329559 37101   31588
5   October  144107 35917   29444
6  November   19432  8587    5382
7  December       0     0       0
```

I want months and fruits name as the heads of the matrix

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  Do you need `library(reshape2);acast(melt(fruits, id.var='Month'), variable~Month, value.var='value')` or is it `as.matrix('row.names<-'(fruits[-1], fruits[,1]))`

Comment: You are saviour. Thank you. I was looking for 2nd answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can subset the 'fruits' column without the first column, change the row names of 'fruits' by the first column and convert to `matrix` (`as.matrix`).

```
as.matrix('row.names<-'(fruits[-1], fruits[,1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want, but it would have been a good idea to show the expected output as @akrun suggests:

```
# convert the number columns to a matrix
Mfruits <- as.matrix( fruits[ , 2:4 ] )
# get the months as column names
row.names( Mfruits ) <- fruits[ , 1 ]
> Mfruits
           Apple Mango Banana
June      149579 36051  28124
July      198742 37228  30354
August    397145 36483  31140
September 329559 37101  31588
October   144107 35917  29444
November   19432  8587   5382
December       0     0      0

# check whether you really have a matrix
str( Mfruits )
int [1:7, 1:3] 149579 198742 397145 329559 144107 19432 0 36051 37228 36483 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : chr [1:7] "June" "July" "August" "September" ...
 ..$ : chr [1:3] "Apple" "Mango" "Banana"
```